# how can i move the content of a svn folder in another?

Tags: svn, directory

we have a svn folder stucture like this:

```
svn-repo
   |
   +------userA
   |        |
   |        +----projAA
   |        |
   |        +----projAB
   |        ...
   |
   +------userB
   |        |
   ...      +----projBA
            |
            +----projBB
            ...
```

with the sources directly under projAA, proj AB, ...

we want to make use of tags and branches in the future. therefore we want to have a structure like this:

```
svn-repo
   |
   +------userA
   |        |
   |        +----projAA
   |        |       |
   |        |       +---tags
   |        |       |
   |        |       +---branches
   |        |       |
   |        |       +---trunk
   |        |       
   |        +----projAB
   |        |       |
   |        |       +---tags
   |        |       |
   |        |       +---branches
   |        |       |
   |        |       +---trunk
   |        ...
   |
   +------userB
   |        |
   ...      +----projBA
            |       |
            |       +---tags
            |       |
            |       +---branches
            |       |
            |       +---trunk
            |
            +----projBB
            |       |
            |       +---tags
            |       |
            |       +---branches
            |       |
            |       +---trunk
            ...
```

now my question is how i could do this automatically?

so far i have written this simple script:

```
@echo off & setlocal

set MY_BAT_FILE=%~nx0
if [%1]==[] goto missing_param

set MY_SVN_PATH=%1
set MY_TMP_PATH=%MY_SVN_PATH%_TMP
set MY_SVN_TRUNK=%MY_SVN_PATH%/trunk
set MY_SVN_TAGS=%MY_SVN_PATH%/tags
set MY_SVN_BRANCHES=%MY_SVN_PATH%/branches
set MY_SVN_MSG="created/edited by: %MY_BAT_FILE%"

svn mkdir %MY_TMP_PATH% -m %MY_SVN_MSG%
svn move %MY_SVN_PATH%/*.* %MY_TMP_PATH% -m %MY_SVN_MSG%
svn mkdir %MY_SVN_PATH% -m %MY_SVN_MSG%
svn mkdir %MY_SVN_TRUNK% -m %MY_SVN_MSG%
svn mkdir %MY_SVN_TAGS% -m %MY_SVN_MSG%
svn mkdir %MY_SVN_BRANCHES% -m %MY_SVN_MSG%
svn move %MY_TMP_PATH%/*.* %MY_SVN_TRUNK% -m %MY_SVN_MSG%

goto END

:missing_param
echo.failed!
echo.
echo.usage:
echo.  %MY_BAT_FILE%  ^<SVN_PATH^>
echo.
echo.parameter
echo.  SVN_PATH:
echo.    path to svn repository/folder (without trailing "/").
goto END

:END
pause
```

but this doesnot work because of `svn move %MY_SVN_PATH%/*.* %MY_TMP_PATH% -m %MY_SVN_MSG%` and `svn move %MY_TMP_PATH%/*.* %MY_SVN_TRUNK% -m %MY_SVN_MSG%`.
because wildcards are not supported.

if i use `svn move %MY_SVN_PATH% %MY_TMP_PATH% -m %MY_SVN_MSG%` and `svn move %MY_TMP_PATH% %MY_SVN_TRUNK% -m %MY_SVN_MSG%` (=without wildcards) then it copies not only the content of the folder, but the hole folder.
which results in `svn-rep/userA/projAA/trunk/projAA_TMP/projAA/` and not in `svn-rep/userA/projAA/trunk/`.

how can i move just the content of an folder to another folder?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a solution.

here is the new script. if anyone is interested in.

```
@echo on & setlocal

set MY_BAT_FILE=%~nx0
if [%1]==[] goto missing_param

set MY_SVN_PATH=%1
set MY_TMP_PATH=%MY_SVN_PATH%_TMP
set MY_SVN_TRUNK=%MY_SVN_PATH%/trunk
set MY_SVN_TAGS=%MY_SVN_PATH%/tags
set MY_SVN_BRANCHES=%MY_SVN_PATH%/branches
set MY_SVN_MSG="created/edited by: %MY_BAT_FILE%"

:: svn mkdir %MY_TMP_PATH% -m %MY_SVN_MSG%  :: dont create the tmp-directory !
:: just make a copy of the original folder
svn copy %MY_SVN_PATH% %MY_TMP_PATH% -m %MY_SVN_MSG%

:: delete the original folder
svn delete %MY_SVN_PATH% -m %MY_SVN_MSG%

:: re-create the initial folder (it is empty now)
svn mkdir %MY_SVN_PATH% -m %MY_SVN_MSG%

:: create empty branches and tags folders
svn mkdir %MY_SVN_TAGS% -m %MY_SVN_MSG%
svn mkdir %MY_SVN_BRANCHES% -m %MY_SVN_MSG%

:: move (same as rename) the temp folder to trunk
svn move %MY_TMP_PATH% %MY_SVN_TRUNK% -m %MY_SVN_MSG%

goto EOF

:missing_param
echo.failed!
echo.
echo.usage:
echo.  %MY_BAT_FILE%  ^<SVN_PATH^>
echo.
echo.parameter
echo.  SVN_PATH:
echo.    path to svn repository/folder (without trailing "/").
goto EOF

:EOF
pause
```

the folders are going thru this steps:

```
1:  //svn-repo/user/proj

2:  //svn-repo/user/proj
    //svn-repo/user/proj_TMP

3:  //svn-repo/user/proj_TMP

4:  //svn-repo/user/proj_TMP
    //svn-repo/user/proj          << this is new created, empty!

5:  //svn-repo/user/proj_TMP
    //svn-repo/user/proj/branches
    //svn-repo/user/proj/tags

6:  //svn-repo/user/proj/branches
    //svn-repo/user/proj/tags
    //svn-repo/user/proj/trunk    << //svn-repo/user/proj_TMP moved (=renamed)
```

Comment: Please add a short explanation how this solved your problem :-)

Comment: I will add an explanation tomorrow, i have just left the office and post via mobile :)

Comment: @AaronDigulla i added an explanation.